# linux evolution task list reminder

Tags: linux, evolution

I have my task list in evolution (mainly so it can sync with my phone and online task list) but I always forget to look at the task list. 
Is there an application or plugin which periodically displays the contents of the tasklist or even better, it briefly displays the most urgent/important tasks when I login? Or anything else which automatically displays the most important tasks.

Currently I have to open the task list and look at them (which I usually forget). I do not mean some kind of alarm when the task is due but more a daily reminder of what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way which works for me.

As soon as I unlock the screen the task list of evolution is shown.

I used a small Python script to do this:

```
import os
import dbus
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop
import gobject
import wnck
import gtk
import pyatspi

# called when screen is locked/unlocked
def handler(active=None):
    if active == 0:
        # screen is unlocked

        screen = wnck.screen_get_default()

        while gtk.events_pending():
            gtk.main_iteration()

        # activate the window whose name ends in 'Evolution'
        for window in screen.get_windows():
            if not window.get_name().endswith('Evolution'):
                continue
            window.activate(gtk.get_current_event_time())

            # press Ctrl, press&release 4, release Ctrl
            pyatspi.Registry.generateKeyboardEvent(37, None, pyatspi.KEY_PRESS)
            pyatspi.Registry.generateKeyboardEvent(13, None, pyatspi.KEY_PRESSRELEASE)
            pyatspi.Registry.generateKeyboardEvent(37, None, pyatspi.KEY_RELEASE)

loop = DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)

# connect to dbus message
bus = dbus.SessionBus()
ss = bus.get_object('org.gnome.ScreenSaver', '/org/gnome/ScreenSaver')
ss.connect_to_signal('ActiveChanged', handler, dbus_interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver')

# loop forever
loop = gobject.MainLoop()
loop.run()
```

The script is run in the background when I login.

Comment: I am newbie to linux, how I can run this script on my laptop? Should I save this script in a text file? what extension the file must have? and how I set the file to run every time I restart my computer?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to display your task list when you start up Evolution.

1. Install xdotool

   ```
   apt-get -y install xdotool
   ```
2. Create a script called evo.sh containing the following commands

   ```
   !/bin/bash
   evolution &
   sleep 5
   evowin=`xdotool search --name "Evolution" | head -2 | tail -1`
   xdotool windowactivate $evowin
   xdotool key ctrl+4
   exit
   ```
3. Make the script executable

   ```
   chmod u+x evo.sh
   ```
4. Run evo.sh

   ```
   ./evo.sh
   ```

Great success!

Comment: `evolution -c tasks` will do the same thing. However, I never close evolution, it is always running. (I never turn off the computer, I use suspend). So this solution is not quite what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you might take a look at http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-812307.html
There seems to be a way to do this using the "alarm" feature.